# How to find largest 10 elements in multi dimentional array?

Tags: java

I hope this will print one largest value. but it need 10 largest elements in an 3D array.

```
public class foo{
    Public static void main(String[] args){

        int row,col,dep=3;
        int[][][] value=new int[row][col][dep];

        /* insert the value from user or initialize the matrix*/
        int max=0;
        for(row=0;row<3;row++)
            for(col=0;col<3;col++)
                for(dep=0;dep<3;dep++)
                    if(value[row][col][dep]>max)
                        max=value[row][col][dep];
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have negative values in the array?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for showing the code that you already have. It’s not that much of an attempt, though. What would you want from us? That we write the code for you (we shouldn’t). An algorithm? A data structure? In this way I find your question unclear, and I’m tempted to vote for closing as too broad, but since you’re new here, I don’t.

Answer (score 2):

You can add all integers into a `List<Integer>`, sort it, and then get the X max numbers of it:

```
public class foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int row = 3, col = 3, dep = 3;
        int[][][] value = new int[row][col][dep];
        value[1][2][1] = 10;
        value[1][0][1] = 15;

        List<Integer> listWithAll = new ArrayList<>();
        /* insert the value from user or initialize the matrix*/
        int max = 0;
        for (row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            for (col = 0; col < 3; col++)
                for (dep = 0; dep < 3; dep++)
                    listWithAll.add(value[row][col][dep]);

        listWithAll.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(listWithAll.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

which prints:

> 15 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

or using Java 8 streams only:

```
List<Integer> max10 = listWithAll.stream()
        .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
        .limit(10)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

max10.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: It’s a fully correct answer (not really sure the questioner deserved it). I like the stream solution, but in that case I would definitely also use streams for converting from 3D array — we wouldn’t even need an explicit intermediate list. `List<Integer> max10 = Arrays.stream(value).flatMap(Arrays::stream).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).boxed().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @OleV.V It would be great if you could expand your comment into an answer, with a few explanatory notes.

Comment: Thanks, @neutrino_logic. [WJS has done just that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58243154/5772882)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with `streams`.  I used a complete 2 x 2 x 2 array to make it easier but it would work with any `int[][][]` array.  Instead of using nested loops, I just `flatMapped` the arrays.

Initialize the array.

```java
      int[][][] v = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}};
```

Now get the top4 values (or top N values) and put them in a list.

```java
      int top4 = 4;
      List<Integer> top4Max =
            Arrays.stream(v).flatMap(Arrays::stream).flatMapToInt(
                  Arrays::stream).boxed().sorted(
                        Comparator.reverseOrder()).limit(top4).collect(
                              Collectors.toList());

      System.out.println(top4Max);
```

Prints

> 8 7 6 5

The `Arrays.stream` strips one level of array.  The  `flatMap` takes those and further flattens them into a `single dimenion` array.  The `flatMapToInt` flattens that into a `stream of ints` where they are sorted and processed into a limited collection.

If required, you could also put them in an array instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, one could create a small array and use it as with a normal findmax function.

```
public class Array_3D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int row = 3, col = 3, dep = 3;
        int[][][] value = new int[row][col][dep];
        value[1][2][1] = 10;
        value[1][0][1] = 15;

        int[] topten = new int[10];  //array to hold max values
        int count = 0;
        int candidate = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < dep; k++) {   
                    if (count < 10) {                 //start with first ten values
                        topten[count] = value[i][j][k];
                        count++;
                    }
                    else {
                        candidate = value[i][j][k];
                        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {   //loop for loading top values
                            if (candidate > topten[x]) {
                                topten[x] = candidate;
                                break;                   //exit on first hit
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(topten[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I don't know which method is faster for large 3D arrays; here we have to run a small loop at every point in the 3D array, vs creating an entirely new list and sorting it. Clearly this wins in memory usage, but not sure about speed. [Edit note this returns an unsorted array of the top ten values as is].